# What do I need to play Disney Infinity 3.0 on Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-eshop, disney-infinity-3.0

I have two figures (the two ones from Zootopia) and next month is my girlfriend's birthday, so I wanted to give her a copy of the game, and I also bought one for me (3.0) and one of those figures, we both have the Wii U console in our respective homes, the question is, do I need another 'base' besides the gamepad for each of us, (can't it 'read' the figures like an amiibo?) and the single copy of the 3.0 game for each one of us?

For example, if I buy two digital copies (on the Nintendo Eshop), and two 'bases' (I don't know how those are called) and we already have the two figures, will it work at the point that we'll be able to play it online/multiplayer?

***I don't have and I'm not planning to get the starter pack, I'm trying to find a solution because it's too expensive.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to play the game, you need:

- A base
- One or more figures
- A compatible console

Each base will support two playable characters as well as a mission pack figure (if needed).  So, if you want to play on both Wii-Us at the same time, you'll need two disks and two bases to support your characters.

If it helps, the PS3, PS4 and Wii-U bases are compatible and can be used on any of those consoles.  The Xbox 360 and Xbox One bases are system specific.